# Having trouble with creating a 2d physics game engine (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics, physics, 2d-games

Hope you'll are doing fine. 
I'm a beginner programmer and recently I've been working on a 2d physics game engine in JavaScript. Everything seemed to be working fine until I have come across an annoying bug in my push mechanic.

I have created a push system with a collidable square (the player) which can push multiple other collidable squares at the same time and stop when the squares hit a wall (which you can't push). However, when the player pushes one or multiple squares at the same time, they all fly to the top of the wall apart from the square which is the closest to the wall (as seen in the video).

[Project Files](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/aaa93cea9ffff4849525d1ca1da53a0020200208014513/afd012)

[Video which shows the problem](http://shorturl.at/hxCX1)

I've been trying to solve this problem for awhile now and I just can't find the perfect solution.

If anyone would be able to help it'd be great. Thank you

```
collisionDetection: function(game) {
    var collisionDetection = function(obj01, obj02) {
        if(obj01.x < obj02.x + obj02.colW &&
            obj01.x + obj01.colW > obj02.x &&
            obj01.y < obj02.y + obj02.colH &&
            obj01.y +obj01.colH > obj02.y) {
                physics.handleCollision(obj01, obj02);
        }
    };     

    for (let i = 0; i < game.gameComponents.length; i++) {

        for (let j = i + 1; j < game.gameComponents.length; j++) {
            const obj01 = game.gameComponents[i];
            const obj02 = game.gameComponents[j];
            collisionDetection(obj01, obj02);
        }
    }
},

    handleCollision: function(obj01, obj02) {

    var tr = obj01.x + obj01.colW // This right side
    var tl = obj01.x // This left
    var tt = obj01.y // This top

    var or = obj02.x + obj02.colW // Other right
    var ol = obj02.x // Other left
    var ot = obj02.y // Other top

    // North, east, south, west of other (around)
    if (obj02.colType == "nesw") {

        // Top of other
        if(obj01.y+obj01.colH>obj02.y && tl + obj01.colW > obj02.x+3 && tl < obj02.x+obj02.colW-3) {
            obj01.y = obj02.y - obj01.colH;
        }
        // Bottom of other
        if(tr > ol + 3 && tl < or - 3 && tt > ot) {
            obj01.y = obj02.y + obj02.colH;
        }
        // Left of other
        if(tl < obj02.x && obj01.y + obj01.colH > obj02.y && obj01.y < obj02.y + obj02.colH) {
            if (obj02.pushable == true ) {

                obj02.x = (obj01.x + obj01.colW) 

            }else {
                obj01.x = (obj02.x - obj01.colW) 
            }


        }
        // right of other
        if(tl > obj02.x && obj01.y + obj01.colH > obj02.y && obj01.y < obj02.y + obj02.colH) {
            obj01.x = obj02.x + obj02.colW;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think the *Project files* link to wrong url?

Comment: I've updated the link thank you. Project Files: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/aaa93cea9ffff4849525d1ca1da53a0020200208014513/afd012